# How can I join two different path under one object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

```
I am trying to add two different source paths under one object but I am not able to do that, could anyone help, please.
```

Like I have two source paths and I want to combine both paths under one object so I can run my code and check the condition with the childitem

```
$RetailSource  = '\Retail P&C Sales Intelligence\*'
$GroupSource = '\Group P&C Sales Intelligence\*'    
$sourcepath = Join-path -path 'c:\uploadtool' -childpath $RetailSource,$GroupSource
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-Path` parameter of Get-ChildItem can take an array of paths to iterate through, so you could do something like this:

```
# create an array of paths and store it in variable $sourcepath
$RetailSource  = 'Retail P&C Sales Intelligence'
$GroupSource   = 'Group P&C Sales Intelligence' 
$sourcepath    = (Join-Path -Path 'c:\uploadtool' -ChildPath $RetailSource),
                 (Join-Path -Path 'c:\uploadtool' -ChildPath $GroupSource)

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcepath { ... }
```

OR

```
$RetailSource  = Join-Path -Path 'c:\uploadtool' -ChildPath 'Retail P&C Sales Intelligence'
$GroupSource   = Join-Path -Path 'c:\uploadtool' -ChildPath 'Group P&C Sales Intelligence' 

Get-ChildItem -Path $RetailSource, $GroupSource  { ... }
```

<sup>Your code made it look as if you wanted to combine 3 pieces into one single full path, where in fact you need two fully combined paths joined as string array. See the [Path parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) on `Get-ChildItem`</sup>

Comment: Actually, I want to upload files from a specific source, like I have two or multiple different sources. so I would like to include that sources under one object to run the below command upload the specific file to the production folder.  I tried to add multiple source paths under the array but it did not work.                                                                                                                    
Get-ChildItem -Path "$source"  -Include '*Group-EIP*', '*Retail-EIP*' -File -Force -Recurse

Comment: @essexlake Just don't put quotes around it. It's an array of paths, not a single string

Comment: @essexlake The first script code shows you how to combine various source path strings into an array (1 single object) and how to use that on Get-ChildItem. In your case this would be `Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcepath  -Include '*Group-EIP*', '*Retail-EIP*' -File -Force -Recurse`. (you forgot the wildcards `*`). Is that not exactly what you wanted?